# Magento 2 Dynamically Add file uploader in system config

Tags: magento2.2.2, file-upload, system-config, file, dynamic-rows

How to add a file uploader render in a dynamically added rows?

something like:
[image]

But in dynamically added Like:

[image]

Let say before or after drop down and the input text field?

Best!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does not fully answer my question but partially and puts it in the right direction:

I added now file uploader look like so:
[image]

Now when I save serialised data looks like this:

```
{
  "_1565251449037_37": {
    "category_id": "5",
    "file_uploaded": {
      "name": "",
      "type": "",
      "tmp_name": "",
      "error": 4,
      "size": 0
    }
  },
  "_1565251729340_340": {
    "category_id": "7",
    "file_uploaded": {
      "name": "wed2b_regions_stores_v1.csv",
      "type": "text\/csv",
      "tmp_name": "\/private\/var\/tmp\/phpZwzFAH",
      "error": 0,
      "size": 10591
    }
  }
}
```

When it return to the page refreshed I am getting the error:
[image]

I understand why the error is because the element is a file element button and it can't be set plus I think magento is expecting the `"file_uploaded"` to be string and is an object and not a string when perhaps value should be `file_uploaded.name`

Any help on this appreciated.

Comment: How you have fixed the error seen in the console?